# php included file execution failure

Tags: php, javascript, css, file, include

Good afternoon everyone. I'm stuck on including a file that has all of my 'head' information in it. I wanted to break down my page so it's simpler and less complicated. in my index.php file i did this;

```
 <?php
 include 'Resources/includes/head.php';
 ?>
```

It finds the file and i know this because in dreamweaver when i go on my index page it comes up as a tab underneath it. However when i view my index page on the local server, it's as if none of the styles or scripts have been applied to the page. This is the code that my head.php file has in it.

```
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/design/icon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: you have problem with your base theme path. you can try checking by removing .. or adding ../ or defining a base path for the folders..

Comment: It finds the folders it just doesn't execute the information within them.

Comment: i have added a sample answer you can try like that..

Comment: Just because Dreamweaver shows a valid path, doesn't mean it's correct. Your IDE is not your server. I am going to guess that the include is wrong (absolute paths are always better than relative paths). What is the source of the page when it's loaded in the browser? Does it have the head.php contents?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this by using a base path

```
<?php
$basepath="http://www.mysite.com/path_to_theme/";
?>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $basepath; ?>/images/design/icon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $basepath; ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="<?php echo $basepath; ?>/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo $basepath; ?>/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: do you have a htaccess in your localhost .. are you able to access the files directly hitting on the url..seems like your files not executing because any blocking policy in the local server

Comment: There's no problems like that, all the links to other pages are working fine and if i was to take the 'head' section out of the file and put it directly in the index.php it would work fine. But i want to minimize the content on index.php because it's getting too crowded. Plus this way i can edit all the content easier

Comment: is header.php path is correct ?.what out put you seeing as html in the view source of any browser.are you able to see the header contents in html ?

Comment: the path is correct because in dreamweaver when you link a style sheet it'll have a "tab" where if you click it you can then change the code within it. So i know that the path to the file is fine and as i've shown before, the content within the 'head.php' is fine because if i were to copy and paste it into my index page and replace 'include', it would work fine. When i preview the page all the content is on the page (that is in the <body> seciton) but no styles or javascripts have been applied to it from the head.php file